# Join 2 lists in one

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I am new in .NET > 2

I have

```
List<Dog> dogs;
List<Cat> cats;
List<Animal> animals;
```

I need to join `dogs` and `cats` in `animals`.

I know that there should be a elegant way to do it using LINQ or stuff from .NET 4, isn't it?

My Initial variant:

```
animals.AddRange(dogs);
animals.AddRange(cats);
```

Comment: I guess we should assume that `Animal` is a common base class for `Dog` and `Cat`?

Comment: @Fredrik Dogs and cats have *nothing* in common. Cats are cute and cuddly. Dogs are big and barky.

Answer (score 4):

.NET 4 makes this relatively easy using generic covariance, yes - although you need to be explicit:

```
animals = dogs.Concat<Animal>(cats).ToList();
```

Alternatively:

```
animals = dogs.Cast<Animal>().Concat(cats).ToList();
```

or:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> dogsAsAnimals = dogs;
animals = dogsAsAnimals.Concat(cats).ToList();
```

Prior to .NET 4, you could use:

```
animals = dogs.Cast<Animal>().Concat(cats.Cast<Animal>()).ToList();
```

Basically the difference with .NET 4 is that there's an implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<Cat>` to `IEnumerable<Animal>`. For *lots* more detail, see [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/).

Comment: Is it possible to use LINQ in this situation?

Comment: @serhio: That *is* using LINQ. `Concat`, `Cast` and `ToList` are parts of LINQ.

Comment: cool :"); ...however, I see two `AddRange` more "readable" that `dogs.Cast<Animal>().Concat(cats).ToList();`